# Query to loop through one table and insert incrementally by group into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help with a sql query. I've got two simple tables, one that contains Channels, each with a unique identifier (ChannelID), and another one to many ID (OtherID). The second one will contain a sort order of each channel as it appears in another query. This sorting table is currently empty and my channels table has a couple thousand records.

The intended result is to loop through each ChannelID by OtherID and insert it incrementally into ChannelSorting, starting the SortOrder seed at 1 again for every new "cluster" of channel id's, grouped by OtherID.

Channels

```
ChannelID    OtherID
---------    -------
1             1
2             1
3             1
4             1
5             2
6             2
```

ChannelSorting (with intended result)

```
ChannelID    SortOrder
---------    ---------
1            1
2            2
3            3
4            4
5            1
6            2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to set the sortorder and insert into the other table.

```
insert into channelsorting (channelid,sortorder)
select channelid,row_number() over(partition by otherid order by channelid) sortorder
from channels
```

Comment: Does this create a new table? The table already exists and there are quite alot of other pieces to it that aren't important to this question. I get a "there is already an object called channelsorting in the database" when I run your example.

Comment: yes..`select .. into` tries to create a new table. use `insert into..select..` as the table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into Channelsorting
select
ch.channelid,
row_number() over (partition by ch.otherid order by ch.channelid)as sorting
from
Channels ch
join
ChannelSorting cs
on cs.channelid=ch.channeleid
```